# How to Update Fusion Map Dynamically From Google Response Spreadsheet of Google Form

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Hi I am pretty new to google maps and fusion tables.

I am trying to update my Web Page([this](http://fanpagedirect.com/pollinator/index.html)) which contains the Google Form and Google IFrame of Map which linked from [Google Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1VnXpMXy4MVyLu2n5r_ECFkBxCLaHtWbjc5mpXA4#rows%3aid=1).

But, The Problem Is that after submitting the form the Location Column of Fusion table is Zipcode(Map Column) is Not updating in Fusion Table So, Depended Web Page IFrame also Not updating.

When I am doing 'Update Fusion Table' from my Form Response Spreadsheet, Fusion table is updating. But I Want Live update of Iframe in my webpage after submitting google Form.

I have Read the Tutorial of chrislkeller.

Thanks in advance for the help/smack-down (whichever it may be)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got the update portion of the script running like it should.

Now in the spreadsheet, go into the script editor (Tools > Script Editor) and choose the Resources menu item and go to All your triggers.

This will open up a "wizard" of sorts that will allow you to run specific functions when the form is submitted.

Here's an example...
[image]

You'd be well to increase the range of data to be sent from the spreadsheet to the table, otherwise only the previous designated range will be sent.

Good luck and feel free to message me off-list if I can help…

Chris K.

Comment: :Thanks for the Quick Response ! But Chrish As your guidance I have done that But Still there is no Update of Fusion Table Map Layer in my Web Page. I have also tried the Trigger on Time Event But, It also not working. Everything is going right but Layer is not updating. I have to done that manually from my Response Style sheet under the Menu 'Data Fusion Update' > 'update Fusion Table'. After that I have to switch on Google Fusion Table and Refresh(F5) page. After that Effect of Location Places are shown.

Comment: Not sure what issues you might be running into. I'm happy to hear the manual sync is working correctly -- at least from what I gather. For me it was just a lot of trial and error until I figured it out. Perhaps post a screenshot of what your triggers look like?